# Merge tag cron-task into cron

Tags: support, retag-request, synonym-request

I think the question's title pretty much covers my suggestion, as we should merge the [cron-task](/questions/tagged/cron-task) tag into [cron](/questions/tagged/cron). There are only 45 questions tagged as `cron-task` at the moment, and the questions' topic could be easily described using the `cron` tag. Having `cron-task` is redundant, mainly because we are on Stack Overflow, a site for programmers. From which, I, and I think many fellow users here, imply, that we ask about how can we design and develop a script which is ran by cron, not about administrative issues with cron (because that is not in the scope of this site).